# I'm looking for inspiration for spells and potions

Tags: fantasy, resources, inspiration

Is there any books out there that details old spells and potions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question

Comment: what would be an appropriate forum to post this on then

Comment: @caulfield1285 please take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages. We are looking for questions that can reasonably have one answer (as opposed to many), are potentially helpful to other users, and are about the craft of writing. We are a Q&A site, not a forum. So "shopping list" questions which can potentially have an infinite number of equally good answers are out of place here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a TTRPG Rulebook. Pathfinder's Core rulebook is found online: Google 'pathfinder core rulebook pdf'

Lots to go on there, and if you need more - find the subsequent additions i.e. Ultimate Equipment, Advanced Players Guide, etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, since spells and potions don't exist in this world, all we have are sources from people who *believed* they existed.

For spells, you could check out the [Malleus Maleficarum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleus_Maleficarum). It's a medieval treatise about witchcraft, mostly written for inquisitors and theologists. In the second section you may find some hypotetical description fon how witches did their spell and rituals, or at least it should give you an idea on what the clergymen of the times believed witches capable of.

For potions, I'd give a look on historical figures - alchemists. Often seen as something like early chemists, alchemists were borderline scientists and magician, and have left a lot of written traces about their procedures and beliefs (e.g. the famous myth of transmuting gold). Among them, you could check out [George Ripley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Ripley_(alchemist)), the alleged author of the somewhat famous [Ripley's scroll](http://www.levity.com/alchemy/rscroll.html), which describes, enigmatically, the procedure to create a Philosopher Stone.

Comment: magic is real though

Comment: @caulfield1285 Believe what you will. My granfather can dispel hexes, but it's a family secret that will pass down to my cousin, so no help there I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicolas Bernal pointed out, pathfinder books are a great resource to inspire you, but they are kind of expensive. So I mind you to use the free app: "Spell Tracker: Pathfinder RPG companion tool"